# Replacing back references in preg_match with string variables

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to template a document, I want to replace section of the document with dynamic text by searching a document for `[%text%]` and replacing it with `$array['text']` or `$text`.  I know I can use `str_replace("[%text%]", $array['text'], $page)`, but I want to find all instances of `[%(.*?)%]` and replace with with `$array[$1]` instead of `$1`.  I've tried using `create_function($matches, $array)`, but it complains about `Missing argument 2 for {closure}()`.

```
$page = preg_replace('#\[%(.*?)%\]#is', $array["$1"], $page);
```

Comment: create_function both parameters will be string and you are passing $array, is $array is string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `preg_match_all('#[%(.*?)%]#is', $page, $matches);` and then

```
if(count($matches == 2))
{
  $key = 0;
  foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $val)
  {
    if(isset($array[$key]))
    {
      $page = str_replace($val, $array[$key++], $page);
    }
    else
    {
      break; // more matches than array elements
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works pretty good for me but, I had to tweak it a little.  $page = str_replace('[%'.$val.'%]', $array[$key], $page); and I removed the break; to prevent it from ending the loop if the $array[$key] wasn't set

Comment: Oh, it has an error. The `$key++` should be in the `str_replace` line. And without tweaks if you change `foreach(array_unique($matches[1]) as $val)` to `foreach(array_unique($matches[0]) as $val)` it will behave the way you meant to be. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

First do a preg_match and find the matching names. Then craete the array with replacements for every found name. Then use preg_replace with the array as second argument, thereby replacing the names with the items from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with preg_replace_callback.

```
<?php
$page = preg_replace_callback('#\[%(.*?)%\]#is',
  function ($m){
    GLOBAL $array;
    return $array[$m[1]];
  }
, $page);
?>
```